# Mean Curvature Vector Field in Calabi-Yau with Boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, complex-geometry

It is well-known that the mean curvature vector field $H$ of a Lagrangian submanifold in a Calabi-Yau manifold $M$ is given by $H=J\nabla \theta$ where $\theta$ is the phase. I am interested in the case where either $M$ is not necessarily compact or has boundary. Does the equality hold in these cases as well? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, there is no notion of a mean curvature vector of an arbitrary manifold. There is a notion of mean curvature vector for a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold. Second of all, this equation only holds for Lagrangian submanifolds. Are you asking about Lagrangian submanifolds with boundary inside of a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy with my question, yes that's what I meant. I'll fix it now.

Comment: So are you asking about submanifolds, possibly non-compact with boundary, or about Calabi-Yau manifolds which are non-compact with boundary? In case of the latter: it does not matter whether $M$ is compact, or has a boundary, for this equality to hold. See the proof given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0104197.pdf for example. If the submanifolds are allowed to have a boundary, I guess it becomes a bit more tricky and I'd have to think about it - maybe someone else can answer that for you.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I had actually seen the same paper but wasn't sure if closedness is secretly used somewhere.